# How to apply a shadow to group of objects without merging in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shadows, object-styles

I have two objects, both on seperate layers. I want to apply a shadow behind both, when I apply a style to a group or selected layers it applies it to both.

I don't want to have to merge the layers as this would be too time consuming over 100s of files and the recorded action doesn't seem to working either.

[image: Shadow added to both files]

[image: Shadow added behind both files]

Comment: Adding a drop shadow to a group containing both layers should work exactly as you want it to

Comment: I'm really unclear:  *"apply a shadow behind both, when I apply a style to a group or selected layers it applies it to both"* -- okay so what's the problem?? Is it that the action can't group layers?

Comment: Why cant you just put both into the same folder and apply the blending styles to that folder in the layers panel
?

Comment: applying the shadow to the group applies it to all the items in the group ... rather than the group as a whole.

Comment: @AasimAzam you're getting shadows from one part of the group on top of another element in the group? If so, you shouldn't be so [edit] to include a screenshot of the layers panel and result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your Ps.

I made a picture to show how the **drop shadow effect** affects the **Group Layer**:

[image]